# how do i create require function on external json file for web app final build on Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

i'm building a quiz web-app that only serve locally on the machine. All logic & architecture are now done. But the only problem left is:how do i make the question list from "questionOptions.js" to be external on production version?
So that i can change the list with out the need to export another build version?

currently, the list is being pull from locally in development mode, and i dont have any idea to load list to be dynamic(which can be edit on final build).

Vue js

```
var looper = new Vue({
  el: "#quiz",
  data: {
    questionList: require("./js/questionsOptions"),
    currentQuestion: 0,
    ...
  }
});
```

questionOptions.js

```
module.exports = [
  {
    title: "Soalan 1",
    questionTitle: 'Ini adalah penyata soalan 1',
    correctAnswer: true,
    answerSelection: [
      {
        name: "Answer 1 A",
        score: true
      },
      {
        name: "Answer 1 B",
        score: false
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Soalan 2",
    questionTitle: 'Ini adalah penyata soalan 2',
    correctAnswer: true,
    answerSelection: [
      {
        name: "Answer 2 A",
        score: true
      },
      {
        name: "Answer 2 B",
        score: false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i might want to change the list content or length in the future, just the question list only on final build. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`require()` is synchronous and executes at build time.

To perform an async request at runtime, you can use [`import()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1). Keep in mind, your app will need to be able to handle the asynchronous loading.

For example

```js
data: {
  questionList: [],
  currentQuestion: 0,
},
async created () {
  this.questionList = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "questionOptions" */
    './js/questionsOptions'
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks @phil, i tried your code but it wasm working. how do i make sure the async function to be done first before running the whole apps?